# Furthest EURO/World Cup progression without regulation time win?

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup, euro

In 2016, Portugal tied every game in their groups to qualify for the elimination rounds. After that, they won against Croatia and Poland in PKs. Their streak stops there since they won against Wales in regulation time to qualify in the finals.

I believe there was a change in the Euro 2016 Group stages to allow the best 3rd to qualify, so I'm not sure it was possible before this change in the Euro, hence why I'm including World Cup. (Not sure how many go through)

Comment: So, what exactly is the question? Do you want the longest streak of ET/KFTM wins or the latest first normal time win?

Comment: Longest streak in a tournament setting. Bonus for qualifications for said tournament (Before group stage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the 1990 World Cup, the Republic of Ireland advanced to the quarter-finals after drawing all three games in the group stage, and then beating Romania in the round of 16 on penalties after a 0-0 draw with Romania. They eventually lost to Italy 1-0. Not only did Ireland not win any of their games, they didn't take the lead in any either.

Also in 1938 World Cup, Sweden got to the quarter-finals without winning a game, but that was less impressive - there was no group stage and their Round of 16 match against Austria was never played and awarded as a walkover.

As for the Euros... well until 1980 the tournament was only four teams. In 1976, Czechoslovakia won the tournament without winning a regulation-time game: they beat the Netherlands 3-1 after extra time in the semis and then West Germany on penalties in the final. But that was only in a two-game tournament. After that, with only the top two qualifying from groups going through, no team has made it without winning at least one group game, until Portugal this year.